# Let $P,Q,R$ to be the statement variables, 1st year Uni student

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Let $P, Q, R$ be statement variables. Determine whether $(\neg R\vee Q) \rightarrow P$ is equivalent to $P\wedge(Q \leftrightarrow R)$.

I have read the textbook and I'm trying all the ways and formulas and can't get answer. Can anyone explain the steps and formulas or rules to use specifically?

Comment: If all else fails, try making a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) and seeing if they match

Comment: https://www.umsu.de/trees/

Comment: @JMoravitz isn't it too complicated to make truth table of all components?

Comment: Quibble: $\rightarrow$, $\leftarrow$, and $\leftrightarrow$ are the propositional connectives. $\implies$, $\Leftarrow$, and $\iff$ are not, they carry semantic meaning. So you should not mix them up. (That was not the OP, it was one of the people who edited the post but I can’t ping them because they have not commented)

Answer (score 1):

[Consider when $P$ and $Q$ are true but $R$ is false.](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#((%C2%ACR%E2%88%A8Q)%E2%86%92P)%E2%86%94(P%E2%88%A7(Q%E2%86%94R)))

Comment: I did what you said, left side one came out as true and right side one came out as false. So it is not equivalent, u mean?

Comment: Exactly, @Iamlostsaveme. Well done :) After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: but one more thing, how would you come up with considering when p and q are true but r is false?

Comment: I used the link provided, which, in turn, uses the [method of analytic tableaux](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux).

Comment: It is also a hint that $Q\leftrightarrow R$ in the RHS, @Iamlostsaveme.